# JQuery JCarousel Auto scroll with another event

Tags: jquery, uiscrollview, jcarousel

I am using the jQuery jCarousel (http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html) with Auto scroll functionality.  I want to include additional functionality to show the current display item.  For example, if I have 6 items, When it moves from right to left, I have a another div which should show the current display item like "Display 1 of 6", "Display 2 of 6" and so on.

I am able to increase/decrease the count wile clicking on the Next/Prev link in my jCarousel.  I want to show the display count even when it auto scrolls.  How to achieve this functionality?

Kindly help me in this regard.

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,

Venkatesh K

Comment: Apply the same logic you are using to update the number with the link to your timer function.

Comment: I am new to jQuery.  I increase/decrease the count using the click event.  It's a built-in event of the jCarousel. Where as the auto scroll event I am not sure, how its getting called.  Also I need to know how to include another event when the auto scroll happens.  Do let me know, if any additional information requried for the same.  Kindly help me in this regard by providing the example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is launch a function if the `autoscroll` scrolls to the next images and then get the index position of the image at position one.

`jCarousel` can call launch a function on `autoscroll` called <kbd>itemVisibleInCallback</kbd>.

(You can know these kind of things by reading [the documentation](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) of `jCarousel`)

Adding this to the `jCarousel` initialisation would be something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        auto: 2,
        wrap: 'last',
        itemVisibleInCallback: changeNumber
    });
});
```

Then we can get the first visible element in the `carousel` by using the <kbd>carousel.first</kbd> element call.

Hence:

```
function changeNumber(carousel){
    $("#update").html("The first image in the row is: "+carousel.first);
};
```

You can find a working example [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kqxb/).

If you would like to add text to each picture, you could then switch this statement and output something different. For example:

```
switch (carousel.first)
{
    case 1: $("#update").html("Hello, how are you?");             break;
    case 4: $("#update").html("I have just been autoscrolled");   break;
    case 7: $("#update").html("Javascript is pretty awesome");    break;
    case 8: $("#update").html("Where's my coffee?");              break;
}
```

You can find an implementation of that [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/t8RDR/).

I hope that answers your question. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Jean-Paul.  I have implemented the similiar functionality through the below code:                     itemVisibleInCallback: { onBeforeAnimation: {},
  onAfterAnimation: showCount}.